# MySQL / Ruby on Rails setup issues

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, macos

I'm trying to get ruby on rails working nicely with MySQL on Mac OS X 10.7.4. I've run into the following issue (I have gem 'mysql2' in my Gemfile):

```
dlopen(/Users/Ringo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@gemset/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

A couple of potential issues: I have installed mysql with the dmg available here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

I don't know if I need some specific mysql client libraries or what. I didn't have to specify a mysql username / password even when I installed that. I did install the prefpane that comes with it and the claim is that mysql is running.

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but I had tons of headaches trying to do Rails development on my MacBook Pro - I now host a virtual Linux box on the MBP and I'll never go back. So much easier to mess around with different configs without touching the OS X environment. Also, when I mess something up I start up a new copy of the VM and start over in 5 seconds flat.

Comment: What version of Rails are you using? You may have better success with the more modern [mysql2 gem](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2).

Comment: @Jim I was working with a co-worker who does that VM trick last night. You could watch the dots being added to the screen one by one as RSpec was running.  Mine would finish all five lines of dots before his even finished one line.

I don't know if it's just his VM setup or what, but IMHO it's worth a an extra hour or two of one-time setup to gain 2 minutes maybe fifteen or twenty times _every single day_.

Comment: @x1a4 - I am now using the mysql2 gem! Works great, thanks. I did need the fix from Benjamin Cox below though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an easy one:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```